# HTTP Vary: Cookie vs Cache-Control: private

Tags: caching, cookies, http-headers, cache-control, vary

I am writing a web application framework. To properly support reverse proxy servers, I want to make sure that whenever the web application is accessing cookie data, pages that are sent to the user are cached only for that user. As far as I know, there are two ways of achieving this:

```
header('Vary: Cookie');
```

or

```
header('Cache-Control: private');
```

The immediate benefit of using `Vary: Cookie` is that a reverse proxy server will cache non-authenticated requests. However, we're using Google Analytics which create cookies through javascript - so I am afraid the Vary: Cookie method is unusable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Cookies set by a script served by a given domain will only be sent to that domain.

The proxy will not receive the cookies set by google analytics.

Comment: Google Analytics does however set cookies on the domain itself (first party cookie), not on googles domain. This is the principle of how it works.

Answer (score 0):

For your case (using Google Analytics), this will not work as GA sets first-party cookies for ".yourdomain.tld"

As of now, I'm seeing the following first party cookies set by Google Analytics:

```
_gat_gtag_UA_#####_# 
_ga 
_gid
```